Can you programmatically trigger process death and restart the app under instrumentation?
I have some mutable state that lives in the Application that I want to make sure persists across process death without manual intervention.
This means I need a way to read the state in the Application, mutate the state via the UI, kill the Application process, and restart the Application process programmatically without any manual intervention.

If you have a rooted device for testing you could use https://Frida.re for process killing and reading internal state of the app after restart.
